# What format is this data in? Sothink's Swf Quicker html5 export, sprite.js

Tags: flash

I exported a swf file using Sothink's Swf Quicker using the 'Export HTML5' option. The exported file is almost perfect.  What I want to know is what format is the data in (I know it is json!), and how do I make the image scale to the size of the browser when the browser window is altered?

Here is a link to a file
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/adi200wad.appspot.com/o/demo2%2Fbifteck2.html?alt=media&token=9d7b49d7-ae62-4c2a-bf86-a1234dd6e222

Here is a sample of the html generated...everything is in the data variable which then gets passed to sprite.js

```
    <body style="overflow:hidden;">
        <script>var data ={
   "BackgroundColor" : "#FFFFFF",
   "FileVersion" : "6",
   "FrameCount" : "76",
   "FrameHeight" : "375",
   "FrameRate" : 12.0,
   "FrameWidth" : "393",
   "Scale":"showall",
   "FrameRect" : {
      "xmax" : 1500,
      "xmin" : 0,
      "ymax" : 1500,
      "ymin" : 0
   },
   "MainFrame" : {
      "type" : 39,
      "ShowFrame" : [
         {
            "depth" : 1,
            "id" : "1",
            "matrix" : "1,0,0,1,0,0",
            "name" : "",
            "replace" : true,
            "type" : 26
         },
```

Comment: The data is in JSON format. What more is there to tell?

Answer (score 0):

sprite.js uses a proprietary format but most of these properties relate to properties in svg